# orderBy with changes in decreasing and increasing sorting

Tags: r

Is there a standard way of sorting a data.frame by several columns, but with changes in decrease or increase? For example, you may want to order a data.frame by one variable (decreasing) and by the next (increasing).

Is there something like:

```
mydf[ order(mydf$myvariable,mydf$myvariable2,decreasing=c(FALSE,TRUE)), ]
```

Comment: Have you read help to `order`? There is useful code in the example section (using `xtfrm` for character variables).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(plyr)
mydf[with(mydf, order(myvariable, desc(myvariable2)), ]

# Or, a little less typing:
arrange(mydf, myvariable, desc(myvariable2))
```

Comment: I like both answers, but admittedly I am a little biased towards the plyr package ;)

Answer (score 5):

Quick workaround:

```
 mydf[ order(mydf$myvariable,-mydf$myvariable2,decreasing=F), ]
```

For factors, strings etc:

```
 mydf[ order(mydf$myvariable,-xtfrm(mydf$myvariable2),decreasing=F), ]
```

Comment: `xtfrm` is the function you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
library(Deducer)
sort(mtcars,by = ~ cyl - mpg)
```