# Obtain the same cross join with merge() and sqldf::sqldf()

Tags: r, sqldf

I have two data frames: `Sales` and `Clients`. I want to perform cross joins on these data frames using `sqldf::sqldf()` and also using `merge()` and obtain the exact same result with both methods.

So far I´ve only been able to obtain two data frames with the rows ordered differently.

This is the code to generate the `Sales` and `Clients` data frames:

```r
set.seed(1)

Sales <- data.frame(
  Product = sample(c("Toaster", "Radio", "TV"), size = 7, replace = TRUE),
  CustomerID = c(rep("1_2019", 2), paste(2:3, "2019", sep = "_"), paste(1:3, "2020", sep = "_"))
  )

Sales$Price <- round(ifelse(Sales$Product == "TV", rnorm(1, 400, 20),
                            ifelse(Sales$Product == "Toaster", rnorm(1, 40, 2), 
                                   rnorm(1, 35, 2))))

Clients <- data.frame(
  CustomerID = c(paste(2:4, "2019", sep = "_"), paste(1:2, "2020", sep = "_")),
  State = sample(c("CA", "AZ", "IL", "MA"), size = 5, replace = TRUE)
  )
```

This is what I got:

```r
library(sqldf)

# cross join with base R
out1 <- merge(x = Sales, y = Clients, by = NULL)

# cross join with sqldf      
out2 <- sqldf("SELECT *
               FROM Sales
               CROSS JOIN Clients")
```

`out1` and `out2` have different row orderings. How can I tweak the `sqldf()` call in order for `out1` and `out2` to be exactly the same?

This is the closest I got:

```r
merge(x = Sales, y = Clients, by = NULL)  

sqldf("SELECT *
       FROM Sales
       CROSS JOIN Clients 
       ORDER BY State DESC, Clients.CustomerID")
```

Comment: With `out1 <- merge(...)` and `out2 <- sqldf(...)`, then `dplyr::arrange(out1, desc(State), CustomerID.y)` makes the two identical (other than column names). That's really just taking your sql `order by` and translating into `dplyr`. I haven't tried offhand the base R equivalent, since you want decreasing in one and not in the other ...

Comment: @r2evans thank you for your comment. Actually I didn't want the results ordered by any particular variable, I just wanted to obtain two equal data frames. The `order by` clause in `sqldf()` and the variables after the `select` clause was just me trying to replicate the default ordering obtained with `merge()` but so far I wasn't successful.

Comment: @r2evans I edited the question to include additional information and make it easier to understand what i´m trying to accomplish.

Comment: One thing when dealing with SQL databases (you may already know this): you cannot trust the order that the data is returned in *unless you explicitly set it* with "order by". It may or may not honor the order of the data that goes into it. Now that's SQL in general, perhaps SQLite honors the natural (imported) order, I don't know. But it sounds like you're trying to get `sqldf` to mimic the order the `merge` outputs, is that correct? Huh. This sounds like an academic pursuit, what's the rationale behind going down this rabbit hole?

Comment: @r2evans yes, that's what I was trying to do. I have some lecture slides with all the table joins using `merge` and I was trying to parallel each of these joins with the equivalent join in `sqldf`. The focus of my course is R, not SQL, but I decided to include some SQL examples (with `sqldf`) so that my students don't  see their first SQL code when already on the job (as happened to me some years ago). I´ve worked with SQL in the past but mainly through R and (in my previous job) SAS, but since I learned dplyr I stopped using `sqldf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think including `ORDER BY` in `sqldf` is important, since it drives home the fact that in SQL, ordering is never guaranteed unless explicitly directed.

If you were doing simple `ORDER BY` with just "increasing" on both variables, then the translation to `order` in R would be direct. However, since one variable is decreasing and one is increasing, `order` by itself doesn't deal with that. However, as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/3316719, we can do the same with `xtfrm`.

```r
out1 <- merge(x = Sales, y = Clients, by = NULL)
out1 <- out1[order(-xtfrm(out1$State), out1$CustomerID.y),]

out2 <- sqldf::sqldf(
  "SELECT *
   FROM Sales
   CROSS JOIN Clients 
   ORDER BY State DESC, Clients.CustomerID")

### proof they are identical
all(unlist(Map(`==`, out1, out2)))
# [1] TRUE
```

The `xtfrm` helper function here allows us to negate the "values" of a column for the purposes of sorting. From `?xtfrm`:

> A generic auxiliary function that produces a numeric vector which will sort in the same order as 'x'.

If the field were already numeric, we could merely do `order(-State, CustomerID.y)`, but the fact that it is `character` requires a further step. Argo `xtfrm`.

---

**Edit**: in comments, it's determined that the OP wants to mimic the sort-order of `merge` in the SQL statement. Unfortunately, because this is a cartesian product of the two frames, no sorting is applied: `merge` merely `cbind`s all rows of the first frame against the first row of the second frame, then repeats with each row of the second.

This can be demonstrated by using some code from `merge`:

```r
nx <- nrow(x) # Sales
ny <- nrow(y) # Clients
expand.grid(seq_len(nx), seq_len(ny))
#    Var1 Var2
# 1     1    1
# 2     2    1
# 3     3    1
# 4     4    1
# 5     5    1
# 6     1    2
# ...
# 33    3    7
# 34    4    7
# 35    5    7
```

where each number is a row from the respective frames (`x` for `Var1`, `y` for `Var2`). If the original data is:

```
## Sales                        ## Clients        
  Product CustomerID Price        CustomerID State
1 Toaster     1_2019    37      1     2_2019    AZ
2   Radio     1_2019    33      2     3_2019    MA
3   Radio     2_2019    33      3     4_2019    AZ
4      TV     3_2019   408      4     1_2020    IL
5 Toaster     1_2020    37      5     2_2020    MA
6      TV     2_2020   408
7      TV     3_2020   408
```

then this results in

```r
out1
#    Product CustomerID.x Price CustomerID.y State
# 1  Toaster       1_2019    37       2_2019    AZ
# 2    Radio       1_2019    33       2_2019    AZ
# 3    Radio       2_2019    33       2_2019    AZ
# 4       TV       3_2019   408       2_2019    AZ
# 5  Toaster       1_2020    37       2_2019    AZ
# 6       TV       2_2020   408       2_2019    AZ
# 7       TV       3_2020   408       2_2019    AZ
# 8  Toaster       1_2019    37       3_2019    MA
# ...
# 33 Toaster       1_2020    37       2_2020    MA
# 34      TV       2_2020   408       2_2020    MA
# 35      TV       3_2020   408       2_2020    MA
```

which will very much destroy any sorting present in `x` (`Sales`), even if `y` (`Clients`) comes pre-sorted (which it does).

**Because of this**, if you want congruity between R and SQL cross-join solutions, I suggest the most transparent/clear way would be to `merge` in R and then apply post-`merge` ordering in a fashion that is similar to SQL. In fact, from a pedagogic perspective, ask the question: *"What ordering makes sense to humans?" If you assert during the lesson plan that ordering may not be assured until explicitly strong-armed into the process (via `dplyr::arrange`, `x[order(...),]`, or SQL's `ORDER BY` clause). Find the intuitive ordering of the data and then demonstrate that in both R and SQL.

Side notes:

1. Your `sqldf` query results in same-named columns, this results in some errors post-`sqldf` if you start playing with columns. This can be mitigated with `select ... as ...` field-naming.
2. Lexicographic sorting of your data is unfortunately counter-intuitive at the moment: having year at the end of a customer id *suggests* (yes, I'm inferring) a timeline of customer onboarding, yet they will sort first by the leading number. Similar to how `"2020-05-04"` sorts correctly even as a string, while `"05/04/2020"` does not, it might support more intuitive sorting to have the most-significant portion be the leading part of id strings. Or make them integers. Or UUIDs (v4, of course), those are always fun.

Comment: @reevans thank you for your answer. It was definitely useful, as it taught me about `xtfrm`, but what I was looking for was some way of modifying only the `sqldf` call in order to obtain the same ordering that `merge` returns by default. After some more experimentation, I realized that the output of `merge` is not ordered by any variable. It shows every row of `x`, in their original order, matched with the first row of `y`, then every row of `x` matched with the second row of `y`, and so on. This is probably why I couldn't replicate the output of `merge` by modifying `order by` in `sqldf`.

Comment: I see. Because you're doing a cartesian product of them, the order is controlled by the input itself, not by any property of the values themselves. If you look at the source for `merge`, you'll see that it is being done silely with `expand.grid` where the first argument is iterated first. I don't know that you can easily mimic in SQL the (lack of) sorting that occurs in `expand.grid`.

Comment: Internally, if `nx <- nrow(x)` and `ny <- nrow(y)`, then the rows of the output are controlled by `expand.grid(seq_len(nx), seq_len(ny))` (where `Var1` now indicates the rows from frame `x` and `Var2` rows from frame `y`).

Comment: In light of that, perhaps it would be instructive to apply an ordering post-`merge` that makes sense given the context of the data, and then replicate that in SQL. (It might be useful if customer IDs did not have year *last* in the string ... that seems to defeat my assumption of ordering by customer id :-).

Comment: Once again, thank you for your valuable insight! Your suggestion of applying a post-`merge` ordering given the context of the data would probably be the best and safest approach for dealing with real life data. I´m aware that cross joining clients and sales tables probably would never make sense, but I wanted to use the same data to demonstrate all the merges. Since this is an academic made-up example, I think I will take your suggestion and use a numerical `CustomerID`, together with a `Clients` table pre-sorted by `CustomerID`. And then use `ORDER BY Clients.CustomerID`

Comment: Anyway, I always intended the `Clients` table to be sorted by `CustomerID`, but when I created the example I neglected how the strings would be sorted. Including the year last in the `CustomerID` the string turns out to be a bad idea.

Comment: @reevans I think it would be useful if you incorporate your last comment (about the post-merge sorting, taking into consideration the context of the data, and subsequent replication in `sqldf`) since it apparently is the next best think to a solution to the impossible question that I unawarely asked. And that, together with a numerical `CustomerID` as you also suggested, is I will do.